# Acknowledgement from Kafka on Produce with spring-integration

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration Kafka (2.1), I am able to successfully send messages to a topic in Kafka.

The native Kafka Client API, gives an option for Callback on successful send. How can I achieve the same with Spring-integration-Kafka. My configurations and code for your reference below.

XML configurations

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka" />

    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        channel="inputToKafka"
                                        kafka-template="template"
                                        topic="test"
                                        sync="true">
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                        <!--<entry key="retries" value="0" />
                        <entry key="batch.size" value="16384" />
                        <entry key="linger.ms" value="0" />
                        <entry key="buffer.memory" value="33554432" /> -->
                        <entry key="key.serializer"
                               value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" />
                        <entry key="value.serializer"
                               value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Java Code to send Message

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("inputToKafka")
    MessageChannel channel;

channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test Message").build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not currently a "messaging" - style call back, but you can register a `ProducerListener` with the `KafkaTemplate`; see [KafkaTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafkatemplate).